# How can we salvage the question about USA/North American-made stationary power tools?

Tags: discussion

[Are any big shop tools manufactured in the USA?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/4671/49) is attracting poor answers that only mention 1 manufacturer. What is the best way to salvage it?

A couple ideas that occurred to me; feel free to suggest others:

- Convert it to a community wiki - so anyone can just edit one answer
- Suggest asking for ways of finding US stationary tool manufacturers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the answer to the question being asked is "yes" at this time -- but the list, and even the answer"yes", may change at any time without notice.

That makes it a bad SE question.

As far as telling folks how to answer this for themselves... LMGTFY and STFW are frowned upon as answers here. Lessons in "search engineering" would be off topic too.

I'm sorry, but I don't think this is fixable without turning it into a different question.

Comment: The possibility of an answer to change over time doesn't make it a bad SE question (any question about electrical code on DIY.SE, for instance, can have answers which are no longer valid when a new version of the NEC is published). Any answer given should be correct at the time it was given, but it is impossible to ensure that a given answer will be correct for all time

Comment: Yeah, I too disagree with that premise that questions whose answers change overtime are unfit for SE and I don't think it's the root of the problem here.  If the question were changed to "Are any shop tools manufactured in the USA in the early 21st century?" it would still not solicit better answers.  That being said, I don't have a different suggestion to fix it.

Comment: That's part of the justification for ruling out product or website recommendations. We don't _have_ to be consistent, but given SE's stated goal of trying to be a crowdsourced FAQ and in the absence of anyone dedicated to ongoing review and maintenance...

Answer (score 0):

Open several new questions, one for each manufacturer: "Are manufacturer X's stationary shop tools made in the USA?" Less useful to the person asking, as it requires knowledge of which manufacturers produce such tools (and they are not the same ones that produce hand tools), but each answer could be specific. That would lead to a lot of very short questions, though. This therefore lends itself more to a community wiki, IMO, so all of the relevant information can be kept together.

As the asker of the original question, googling does not always produce good (or valid) results for this question, which is why I asked it in the first place. While there are lists which collect information about products made in the USA (one of which was linked in one of the answers), they do not typically include products which used to be made here (e.g., Delta). Given that buying used tools is a good way to get into woodworking, knowing I can get an old Delta table saw which was made in the USA is good information, even if I can't get a new Delta made in the US.